# WPF Listbox items with name on mouseover or active

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, listbox

I've tried several different solutions to this, but can't land on one that meets all of my needs.

We have an observable collection of objects that each have a status and a name. It's a sort of task-list of running items. To display this list in WPF, we have some code that represents each item as an ellipse with some colors and animations.

The problem is that we want to display the name of the item as a 'popup' both on mouseover, or when the task is in a given state.

---

**Attempt #1**

My first attempt implemented this as a Datatemplate (to be used as an ItemTemplate) with an actual WPF Popup. I implemented two datatriggers - one for mouseover and one for task state. I positioned the popup based on my ellipse and everything was great. However, moving the window or switching to a different window left the popup on top of everything.

---

**Attempt #2**

Instead of using the popup I used a textbox in a canvas. This works great until the Datatemplate is used in the Listbox. The item host (stackpanel) ends up clipping the string.

Here's example code:

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="EllipseTemplate">
    <Grid Height="40" Width="40">
        <Canvas Name="PopupCanvas" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Width="500">
            <TextBlock Name="PopupName"
                   Width="{Binding ElementName=PopupCanvas, Path=ActualWidth}"
                   Text="{Binding}"
                   Background="Transparent"
                   FontSize="16" HorizontalAlignment="Center" TextAlignment="Center" FontWeight="Bold" 
                   Canvas.Top="-25"
                   Visibility="Collapsed"
                   />
        </Canvas>
        <Ellipse x:Name="Ellipse" Height="25" Width="25" Margin="0"
                 HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"
                 Fill="Green" 
                 RenderTransformOrigin="0.5, 0.5" StrokeThickness="0.5" Stroke="Black">
        </Ellipse>
    </Grid>
    <DataTemplate.Triggers>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsMouseOver, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" Value="True">
            <Setter TargetName="PopupName" Property="Visibility" Value="Visible" />
        </DataTrigger>
    </DataTemplate.Triggers>
</DataTemplate>

<Grid Name="Test" Background="LightGoldenrodYellow" ClipToBounds="False" Margin="50">
    <ListBox Name="OverlayTest" 
             Background="CornflowerBlue" 
             BorderThickness="0" 
             VerticalAlignment="Center" 
             Margin="10" 
             ClipToBounds="False" 
             ItemTemplate="{StaticResource EllipseTemplate}">
        <sys:String>Very long string that will get clipped</sys:String>
        <sys:String>Two</sys:String>
        <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" IsItemsHost="True" Margin="10,50,10,50" ClipToBounds="False"/>
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
    </ListBox>
</Grid>
```

[image: Example of clipping]

---

**Attempt #3**

I moved my canvas/textbox outside of the datatemplate and create a grid to put it above the listbox of ellipses. This works from a layout perspective, but creates a big mess in terms of checking for mouseover and centering the textbox on the control that's active/hovered.

---

So that leaves me without an implementation that works the way I want. Anyone have any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok here I have another idea. I had problem with the `ListBox` before. Try replacing the `ListBox` with an `ItemsControl`.

Answer (score 0):

Attempt #2 sounds like is working fine. You should be able to solve the issue of the clipping using one of these solutions (or all of them):

1. Set the `ClipToBounds` property of the `ListBox` to `false`
2. Set the `ClipToBounds` property of the `Stackpanel` to `false`

Comment: Yeah, you'd think that would work, but it doesn't. I've tried adding ClipToBounds=False on everything and it doesn't help.

Comment: In the XAML that you posted the `Grid` in the data template and the `Canvas` called  `PopupCanvas` don't have ClipToBounds property set. Also I know it has nothing to do with the problem but I just notice that the `TextBox` has `Visibility = Collapsed`. And another thing I would try is instead of using a `Canvas` to place the `TextBox`, I would use the `ColumDefinitions` and `RowDefinition` of `Grid` to arrange the template.

Comment: I think the problem might be the `ClipToBound` property of the `Grid` and/or `Canvas` because you gave a fix `Width` to the `Grid`. Try that. This problem could because the text is to large to fit in a `Grid` of `Width` 40 so is clipped.

Comment: Added ClipToBounds=false to the canvas and grid with no change. Also changed the TextBlock's visibility with no effect.

It's worth noting that the EllipseTemplate used as a content control works as expected with no clipping (even if arranged in a stackpanel with other EllipseTemplates). The clipping only occurs when it's used in conjunction with the listbox.

Comment: Ok here I have another idea. I had problem with the `ListBox` before. Try replacing the `ListBox` with an `ItemsControl`.

Comment: Also you could try to leave all the `ClipToBounds` inside the template set to `True` and remove the `Width` property of the `TextBox`.

Comment: I followed your suggestion of replacing the ListBox with an ItemsControl and the clipping went away. The ItemsControl is more in line with the functionality we required anyway. I can't select a comment as the answer, if you repost it as an answer I'll select it.

Comment: Ok. I just reposted the comment as answer. I am glad I could help.